# How to Serialize a class from list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of a class and I would like to know how to serialize it to `XElement`.

For example I have a class:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Order 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string OrderTitle { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string DestinationAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have a list of the above class and I would like to know how to serialize it?

Comment: you need to use the `NetDataContractSerializer` or the `DataContractSerializer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enter var templates = from t in response.Descendants("OrderList")
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        orderId = t.Element("OrderId").Value.ToString(),
                                        orderTitle = t.Element("OrderTitle").Value.ToString(),
                                        DestinationAddress = t.Element("DestinationAddress").Value.ToString(),
                                        PhoneNumber = t.Element("PhoneNumber").Value.ToString()
                                    };code here
```

Do the above way where `arrayOfNotaryOrderDocumentsSet.ToList()` is to be your orderlist and you can choose the node names as you wish. I have given `Order`.

Answer (score 1):

Construct your list `List<Order>`.. use Serializator class (From Code Project)

```
public class Serializator
{
    public static string SerializeLinqList<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(writer, list);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static List<T> DeserializeLinqList<T>(string xml)
    {
        List<T> list;

        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            list = dcs.ReadObject(reader) as List<T>;
        }
        if (list == null) list = new List<T>();
        return list;
    }
}
```